# How to vertical-align display:inline (not inline-block) elements in a div?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I have searched for a long time to find an answer, but nowhere have I found a solution...

I have made an unordered list of links and I have put them under the header, like a nav bar. However, in IE (yes that demon..) my links appear not align to the middle. Below is my code...

Please help!

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="dummyPage.html">Company Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="phil-vision.html">Philosophy-Vision</a></li>
                <li><a href="buslines.html">Products/Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="structure.html">Company Structure</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

#menu{float:right;text-align:center;background:#B1A17A;width:100%;}
#menu ul li{ display:inline; list-style-type:none;}
#menu ul li a{padding:0px 10px; font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; margin:0px 5px; font-weight:bold; vertical-align: middle; color:#5F501D;}
```

Comment: The closing tag is missing under products/Service `<a href="buslines.html">Products/Services</a>`. Try closing that and see weather it works fine or not.

Comment: oh, yes. however, that doesn't seem to fix it...

Comment: what version of IE are you using? It works fine for me.

Comment: Seems to affect <= IE7 only.

Comment: It works fine for me in IE 9. Send a screenshot of how it looks at your end.

Comment: Try putting `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >` in your head, otherwise IE defaults to quirks mode which displays pretty much everything wrong.

Comment: http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/3792/94690326.png

Comment: gaynorvader, you are the MAN! However, will it be compatible with other IE versions?

Comment: what about display table-cell

Answer (score 0):

Try using this trick:

```
line-height: 200%;
```

Works in your case. The percentage depends on the height of the tag.